# How to understand movement in expanding universe?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, space-expansion

I know that universe is expanding equally between every pair of points but it was a single point in it's very past... so I was wondering if we could locate this center point of universe. Now I know that we can't and read (on this site) that whatever direction would we go - it would take us closer and closer to big bang... it makes me wonder - if we will trying to get there, there will be our new starting point so going back should take us even closer to this big bang but well, we should have the opportunity to go back to our 1st starting point and it was "farther" before, not closer at all.

Also, as the universe is still expanding and the stars will eventually run out of fuel, would it be possible to try to escape from the situation by flying ahead the big bang and reaching parts of universe that have their state similar to past of "our part of the universe"? Does it mean that the universe is creating itself all the time and dying all the time too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever direction you *look*, you are looking back to a *time* closer to the Big Bang. I'm guessing that's what you read. After all, there is no location in space of the Big Bang (I can elaborate further on this if desired, but I suspect it has been answered in another question), so anywhere you move won't get you any closer to a point that doesn't exist.

As to the second part of your question, sadly the answer is **no**, not at all. Anywhere you can get to by going no faster than the speed of light will be further along in its cosmic evolution than we are here and now. There is no way your future can be in the past so to speak. The whole universe is aging uniformly, and so the stars will eventually die everywhere.

[Regarding those star deaths, though, that will not happen for a very long time, even by the universe's standards. Stars somewhat smaller than our Sun have lifetimes on the order of 100 billion years. For comparison, the universe is only about 14 billion years old right now. Even if stars stopped forming today, solar systems around such stars will go on pretty much unchanged for a *very* long time.]

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand that it's about light lag, not the nature of space... I'm aware of that it's not human problem but I was thinking more about future of life in generall - if it could last forever... I still have hope though: multiverse, big collapse... too bad the spieces of that nature will never have any contact with humans - and that's what saddens me, no point of our existence by "everything's standards". ;-)